# How does the system know about the type of address it is pointing to in case of a rvalue?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, rvalue, lvalue

I have some doubt (possibly a misconception) regarding the concept of rvalues when it comes to pre-increment or post-increment. Consider the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[10];
    int *ptr = a;
    printf("%d", *++ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Here, in the `*++ptr` expression, first `++ptr` is evaluated, which returns the address of `a[1]`, which is an rvalue. My question is when we then dereference that rvalue (address) using the `*` operator, how does the system know how many bytes of memory to fetch? Because `++ptr` is just an rvalue and there is no way of knowing from an rvalue what type of data it is pointing to (address/constant).

On the contrary, when we do something like `*ptr`, then the system knows to take 4 bytes or 2 bytes (depending on the size of `int`) because `ptr` and `*ptr` are both treated as lvalues and the system knows the type of data `ptr` is pointing to.

Can you clear my misunderstanding/misconception on this?

Comment: @AdrianMole okay, I was not aware of the fact that the returned rvalues have the type of the data they are returning. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An rvalue *does* have a type – in the case of the prefix (and postfix) increment and decrement operators, that type is the same as the type of the operand. So, if `ptr` is declared as `int *ptr;`, then the type of the result of `++ptr` is also `int*`.

If rvalues did not have types, then array access would be effectively meaningless, because the expression, `a[i]` (where `a` is an array of type `T`) is ***exactly equivalent to*** `*(a + i)`, where the pointer arithmetic and subsequent dereferencing can *only* be properly performed if the rvalue result of the `a + i` operation maintains the type of the first (in this case) operand (which will be treated as a pointer to the first element of the array, thus a `T*`).

There are some 'gotchas' though, when using the results of operation expressions as types. In the following code, we can see that the result type of `++c` is (like `c` itself) a `char`; however, the result type of `c + 1` is an `int` (whose size, on my platform, is 4 bytes):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c = 42;
    printf("%zu %zu %zu\n", sizeof(c), sizeof(++c), sizeof(c + 1)); // Shows: 1 1 4
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: got the concept clearly. Thank you for the detailed explanation. I appreciate it :)